# How do I keep destination table content controls in Word when pasting information from Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a table in a Word document 2010.  Each field/cell contains a content control (date picker, rich text, etc.).  I need my users to be able to paste data from Excel or wherever into this Document/template... I'll later save the information to a database using VSP.

My problem is that when the data from Excel is pasted into the Word table the content controls are removed leaving only the data.

I tried messing with the content control locking, pasting one column at a time, and pasting one cell at a time...  one cell at a time worked but is not optimal.

Pictures shown in design mode for illustration

Table with content controls before paste:

[image]

After paste:

[image]

Is there a way to paste table data into Word and not lose the content controls?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of,  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specific problem: "...and pasting one cell at a time... one cell at a time worked but is not optimal... Is there a way to paste table data into Word and not lose the content controls?"

That's the ONLY way it's going to work using Copy/Paste. These content controls are IN table cells and there's no way to paste a set of Excel cells so that the data flows into the content controls of multiple cells in a Word table.

Otherwise, you'd need a coded solution that reads each Excel cell and writes the information to the correct "target" in the Word document. If these content controls are linked to a Custom XML Part, then most efficient would be writing directly to that XML.